# 403 You are not allowed to perform this action. yii2 on signup page after login

Tags: php, yii2

When i, through url pass the address as index.php?r=site/login then there appears **login form** & that works fine. But when i pass as `index.php?r=site/signup` then it shows me above error. I am not getting this

```
my access control is like this
    return [
        'access' => [
            'class' => AccessControl::className(),
            'only' => ['logout', 'signup'],
            'rules' => [
                [
                    'actions' => ['signup'],
                    'allow' => true,
                    'roles' => ['?'],
                ],
                [
                    'actions' => ['logout'],
                    'allow' => true,
                    'roles' => ['@'],
                ],
            ],
        ],
        'verbs' => [
            'class' => VerbFilter::className(),
            'actions' => [
                'logout' => ['post'],
            ],
        ],
```

Comment: Your rule  allow the access  to signup action only for  guest  (not logget ) user .

Comment: Exactly what @scaisEdge said. You are probably logged in and trying to access `signup` action but you're not allowed (`'roles' => ['?']`).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Yii2: Signup page shows error "403 forbidden you are not allowed to access the page"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27380297/yii2-signup-page-shows-error-403-forbidden-you-are-not-allowed-to-access-the-p)

Comment: remove `signup` from the `only` property